# Tabular information tableview or listview

Tags: android, listview, tableview

What would be better for presenting a results table within an Android application where all the columns and rows have uniform size. A table view, or a list view with an custom list view adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of data? How much data?

A list view is a far more complicated view, but it allows you to show datasets that are infinitely large (millions and millions is ok). A table view is much simpler, but if you try to use one to display even a moderate number of rows you will start to run into memory issues, depending on how complex the data in each row is.

Comment: Thanks in the end I ended up using a list view with a custom adapter and it worked very well.

Answer (score 1):

every time I start to think `TableView` and start putting together a layout, I realize it just doesn't feel like I want it to, and that `ListView` with horizontal `LinearLayout`s is the way to go.

plus, putting together a custom adapter based on `BaseAdapter` is really straightforward, nothing anyone should be put off by